# A Rust iterator to match and replace subsequences

Tags: iterator, rust

I needed to do transformations on a data stream, not on an element-by-element basis, but on subsequences. This is what I've come up with:
https://github.com/peterjoel/rust-iter-replace/blob/master/src/lib.rs

I am relatively new to Rust, and would love some feedback on any areas of the code: style, design, memory/performance no-nos. But performance (throughput) is particularly important in this application, as I'll be using it to "compress" very large (multi GB) pieces of data, in memory and on disc.

### Design Overview

The central struct `Replace`, keeps track of two buffers: `buffer_out` and `buffer_in`, a set of partial match `candidates` and some other members for keeping track of state between invocations of `next()`.

`buffer_out` is data that is fully processed and ready to pass to the next iterator adapter - this will either contain unmatched data, or the full replacement sequence. `buffer_in` contains data that may or may not match, and gets copied to `buffer_out` as soon as it can be shown that it doesn't match and gets erased when it does. I chose a `VecDeque` for `buffer_out` because it generally gets written to at the back and read from at the start. As I write this, I realise that `buffer_in` could have been just a `Vec`. Maybe I'll change that.

The `BTreeSet`, `candidates`, keeps track of the index when the first item of a partial match occurred. As soon as a partial match no longer matches then it is discarded. I chose a `BTreeSet` because I needed to access the smallest element to know when I can flush any part of `buffer_in`. But actually its elements are added in size order - which I'm not taking advantage of here - so there could be a better data structure which can exploit that invariant.

The section of code where I remove elements from the `candidates` set isn't great. I originally wrote a trait and had it as a method of `BTreeSet`, but I had some errors (I forgot now) to do with the type signature, where I couldn't get it to match the expected type of the predicate used by `filter`. I may revisit that.

### Source

```
use std::collections::{BTreeSet};
use std::collections::VecDeque;

pub struct Replace <'a, I, T: 'a + Ord > {
    iter: I,
    buffer_out: VecDeque<T>,
    buffer_in: VecDeque<T>,
    replace_from: &'a [T],
    replace_with: &'a [T],
    candidates: BTreeSet<usize>,
    index: usize,
    flushed_index: usize,
}

impl <'a, I, T> Replace <'a, I, T> where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Eq + Ord + Copy {
    pub fn adapt(iter: I, replace_from: &'a [T], replace_with: &'a [T]) -> Replace<'a, I, T> {
        Replace {
            iter: iter,
            buffer_out: VecDeque::new(),
            buffer_in: VecDeque::new(),
            replace_from: replace_from,
            replace_with: replace_with,
            candidates: BTreeSet::new(),
            index: 0,
            flushed_index: 0,
        }
    }

    fn fill_buffer(&mut self) {
        'consume: while let Some(item) = self.iter.next() {
            self.index += 1;
            // buffer all incoming items
            self.buffer_in.push_back(item);
            // Prune existing partial match candidates that don't match the next item
            let removes: Vec<_> = self.candidates.iter().cloned()
                .filter(|start_index| {
                    self.replace_from[self.index - *start_index] != item
                }).collect();
            for r in removes {
                self.candidates.remove(&r);
            }
            // Keep track of new partial match candidates
            if self.replace_from[0] == item {
                self.candidates.insert(self.index);
            }
            // if the length of the first match is the length of the replace sequence then it's a complete match
            match self.candidates.iter().cloned()
                .next()
                .into_iter()
                .find(|x| self.index - x + 1 == self.replace_from.len()) {
                    None => {
                        // We can flush the inbound buffer up to the first partial match
                        // (or the full buffer if there are no partial matches)
                        let flush_index = self.candidates.iter().next().map(|x| x - 1).unwrap_or(self.index);
                        if flush_index > self.flushed_index {
                            let mut flush: VecDeque<_> = self.buffer_in.drain(0 .. flush_index - self.flushed_index).collect();
                            self.buffer_out.append(&mut flush);
                            self.flushed_index = flush_index;
                            break 'consume;
                        }
                    },
                    Some(_) => {
                        // A match! So replace it and clear all the partial matches
                        self.candidates.clear();
                        for &x in self.replace_with.iter() {
                            self.buffer_out.push_back(x);
                        }
                        self.buffer_in.clear();
                        self.flushed_index = self.index;
                        break 'consume;
                    }
                }
        }
    }

}


pub trait ReplaceIter<'a, I, T> where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Ord {

    fn replace(self, from: &'a [T], to: &'a [T]) -> Replace<'a, I, T>;
}

impl <'a, I, T> ReplaceIter<'a, I, T> for I where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Eq + Ord + Copy {

    fn replace(self, from: &'a [T], to: &'a [T]) -> Replace<'a, I, T> {
        Replace::adapt(self, from, to)
    }
}


impl <'a, I, T> Iterator for Replace <'a, I, T> where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Eq + Ord + Copy {

    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        if self.buffer_out.len() == 0 {
            self.fill_buffer();
        }
        self.buffer_out.pop_front()
    }

}
```

And tests, which show the usage:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    pub fn test_replace_simple() {
        let v: Vec<u32> = vec![1,2,3].into_iter().replace(&[2], &[10]).collect();
        assert_eq!(v, vec![1,10,3]);
    }

    #[test]
    pub fn test_replace_longer() {
        let v: Vec<u32> = vec![3,4,5,6,7,8,9].into_iter().replace(&[4,5], &[100]).collect();
        assert_eq!(v, vec![3,100,6,7,8,9]);
    }

    #[test]
    pub fn test_replace_multi() {
        let v: Vec<u32> = vec![3,4,5,6,4,5,9].into_iter().replace(&[4,5], &[100,200,300]).collect();
        assert_eq!(v, vec![3,100,200,300,6,100,200,300,9]);
    }

    #[test]
    pub fn test_nearly_match() {
        let v: Vec<u32> = vec![3,4,5,6].into_iter().replace(&[4,5,1], &[100,200]).collect();
        assert_eq!(v, vec![3,4,5,6]);
    }

    #[test]
    pub fn test_replace_overlapping() {
        let v: Vec<u32> = vec![3,4,5,4,5,4,9].into_iter().replace(&[4,5,4,5], &[100]).collect();
        assert_eq!(v, vec![3,100,4,9]);
    }
}
```

Comment: [This has been cross-posted to Reddit and received some answers there.](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/4dan5a/can_anyone_review_my_code/)

Answer (score 5):

The `'consume` label is a bit strange; just `return` instead.

This is a bit ugly:

```
match self.candidates.iter().cloned()
    .next()
    .into_iter()
    .find(|x| self.index - x + 1 == self.replace_from.len()) {
        None => {
            ...
        },
        Some(_) => {
            ...
        }
    }
```

You can simplify this with `any` and splitting this onto a new line:

```
let complete_match = self.candidates.iter().cloned().next().into_iter()
                     .any(|x| self.index - x + 1 == self.replace_from.len());
if complete_match {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

The

```
.iter().cloned().next().into_iter().any(|x| self.index - x + 1 == self.replace_from.len())
```

part is ugly; using `.into_iter().any()` on an `Option` to test it like this is odd, and the `cloned` is unneeded. How about

```
.first().map_or(false, |x| *index - x == replace_from.len() - 1);
```

The `complete_match` case always returns, so we can drop the `else`:

```
let full_match = self.candidates.first().map_or(false, |x|
    *index - x == replace_from.len() - 1
);
if full_match {
    // A match! So replace it and clear all the partial matches
    self.candidates.clear();
    for &x in self.replace_with.iter() {
        self.buffer_out.push_back(x);
    }
    self.buffer_in.clear();
    self.flushed_index = self.index;
    return;
}
// We can flush the inbound buffer up to the first partial match
// (or the full buffer if there are no partial matches)
let flush_index = self.candidates.iter().next().map(|x| x - 1).unwrap_or(self.index);
if flush_index > self.flushed_index {
    let mut flush: VecDeque<_> = self.buffer_in.drain(0 .. flush_index - self.flushed_index).collect();
    self.buffer_out.append(&mut flush);
    self.flushed_index = flush_index;
    return;
}
```

Then

```
for &x in self.replace_with.iter() {
    self.buffer_out.push_back(x);
}
```

is just

```
self.buffer_out.extend(self.replace_with);
```

Later

```
self.candidates.iter().next().map(|x| x - 1).unwrap_or(self.index)
```

is just

```
self.candidates.iter().next().map_or(self.index, |x| x - 1)
```

Idiomatic styling seems to be no spaces around `..`. So

```
self.buffer_in.drain(0 .. flush_index - self.flushed_index).collect()
```

should be

```
self.buffer_in.drain(..flush_index - self.flushed_index).collect()
```

That said, all of

```
let mut flush = self.buffer_in.drain(..flush_index - self.flushed_index).collect();
self.buffer_out.append(&mut flush);
```

is better as

```
let flush = self.buffer_in.drain(..flush_index - self.flushed_index);
self.buffer_out.extend(flush);
```

`candidates` should be a `Vec`, since you don't really use the fact it's a `BTreeSet` usefully. The removal then looks like

```
self.candidates.retain(|start|
    self.replace_from[self.index - *start] == item
);
```

...except for the fact that `retain` borrows `self` mutably so `self.replace_from` doesn't work. This is fixable with a destructuring assignment.

```
{
    let Replace { ref mut candidates, ref replace_from, index, .. } = *self;
    candidates.retain(|start|
        replace_from[index - *start] == item
    );
}
```

Though at this point it might make sense to just do this at the start of the function. This adds a bit of length but simplifies things.

`candidates` should really be inserted into before `index` is incremented. This lets us work with more natural half-open ranges. We can also skip the conditional for `candidates.push` by just reusing the `if` in `candidates.retain`.

```
let Replace {
    ref mut iter,
    ref mut buffer_out,
    ref mut buffer_in,
    replace_from,
    replace_with,
    ref mut candidates,
    ref mut index,
    ref mut flushed_index
} = *self;

for item in iter {
    buffer_in.push_back(item);
    candidates.push(*index);
    candidates.retain(|&start| replace_from[*index - start] == item);
    *index += 1;

    let full_match = candidates.first().map_or(false, |start|
        *index - start == replace_from.len()
    );
    if full_match {
        // Replace it and clear all the partial matches
        candidates.clear();
        buffer_out.extend(replace_with);
        buffer_in.clear();
        *flushed_index = *index;
        return;
    }
    // We can flush the inbound buffer up to the first partial match
    // (or the full buffer if there are no partial matches)
    let flush_index = candidates.iter().next().unwrap_or(index);
    if flush_index > flushed_index {
        let flush = buffer_in.drain(..flush_index - *flushed_index);
        buffer_out.extend(flush);
        *flushed_index = *flush_index;
        return;
    }
}
```

Later, we have

```
pub trait ReplaceIter<'a, I, T> where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Ord {

    fn replace(self, from: &'a [T], to: &'a [T]) -> Replace<'a, I, T>;
}

impl <'a, I, T> ReplaceIter<'a, I, T> for I where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Eq + Ord + Copy {

    fn replace(self, from: &'a [T], to: &'a [T]) -> Replace<'a, I, T> {
        Replace::adapt(self, from, to)
    }
}
```

which is nicer as

```
pub trait ReplaceIter<'a, I, T> {
    fn replace(self, from: &'a [T], to: &'a [T]) -> Replace<'a, I, T>;
}

impl <'a, I, T> ReplaceIter<'a, I, T> for I where
    I: Iterator<Item=T>,
    T: Eq + Clone
{
    fn replace(self, from: &'a [T], to: &'a [T]) -> Replace<'a, I, T> {
        Replace::adapt(self, from, to)
    }
}
```

Note how we no longer need `Ord` and `Copy` was changed to `Clone`. This requires minor changes to the code; we need to do this in the right order:

```
candidates.push(*index);
candidates.retain(|&start| replace_from[*index - start] == item);
buffer_in.push_back(item);
```

(else `item` is moved by `push_back` before `retain` can use it) and we need to `extend` cloned values:

```
buffer_out.extend(replace_with.iter().cloned());
```

---

Here's the code in entirety

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

pub struct Replace <'a, I, T: 'a> {
    iter: I,
    buffer_out: VecDeque<T>,
    buffer_in: VecDeque<T>,
    replace_from: &'a [T],
    replace_with: &'a [T],
    candidates: Vec<usize>,
    index: usize,
    flushed_index: usize,
}

impl <'a, I, T> Replace <'a, I, T> where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Eq + Clone
{
    pub fn adapt(iter: I, replace_from: &'a [T], replace_with: &'a [T]) -> Replace<'a, I, T> {
        Replace {
            iter: iter,
            buffer_out: VecDeque::new(),
            buffer_in: VecDeque::new(),
            replace_from: replace_from,
            replace_with: replace_with,
            candidates: Vec::new(),
            index: 0,
            flushed_index: 0,
        }
    }

    fn fill_buffer(&mut self) {
        let Replace {
            ref mut iter,
            ref mut buffer_out,
            ref mut buffer_in,
            replace_from,
            replace_with,
            ref mut candidates,
            ref mut index,
            ref mut flushed_index
        } = *self;

        for item in iter {
            candidates.push(*index);
            candidates.retain(|&start| replace_from[*index - start] == item);
            buffer_in.push_back(item);
            *index += 1;

            let full_match = candidates.first().map_or(false, |start|
                *index - start == replace_from.len()
            );
            if full_match {
                // Replace it and clear all the partial matches
                candidates.clear();
                buffer_out.extend(replace_with.iter().cloned());
                buffer_in.clear();
                *flushed_index = *index;
                return;
            }
            // We can flush the inbound buffer up to the first partial match
            // (or the full buffer if there are no partial matches)
            let flush_index = candidates.iter().next().unwrap_or(index);
            if flush_index > flushed_index {
                let flush = buffer_in.drain(..flush_index - *flushed_index);
                buffer_out.extend(flush);
                *flushed_index = *flush_index;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}


pub trait ReplaceIter<'a, I, T> {
    fn replace(self, from: &'a [T], to: &'a [T]) -> Replace<'a, I, T>;
}

impl<'a, I, T> ReplaceIter<'a, I, T> for I where
    I: Iterator<Item=T>,
    T: Eq + Clone
{
    fn replace(self, from: &'a [T], to: &'a [T]) -> Replace<'a, I, T> {
        Replace::adapt(self, from, to)
    }
}


impl<'a, I, T> Iterator for Replace<'a, I, T> where
    I: Iterator<Item=T>,
    T: Eq + Clone
{
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        if self.buffer_out.len() == 0 {
            self.fill_buffer();
        }
        self.buffer_out.pop_front()
    }
}
```